# Why is Compiz crashing whenever I try to load saved settings?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, compiz

I recently installed a fresh version of 11.04 to replace a previous installation of 10.10.

I had a .profile file saved that had all my preferences for Compiz. Windows wobbled just right, there was just the right amount of flame when I closed windows, I had all my shortcut keys and desktop cube effects set perfectly.

However, whenever I try to import my .profile file, Compiz dies. All the window frames disappear, none of the settings take effect, and some windows become unclickable.

The only way to get back to usability is to reset to default and then reboot.

(By the way, I'm using Gnome still... a.k.a Ubuntu "classic". I'm not interested in Unity for my desktop computer.)

What's going on? Can't I get my saved preferences back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably cannot recover your saved settings because of the fact that the profile would have been saved with an older version of compiz that what is found in Natty, and quite likely cannot be loaded.

If the profile is a text file (I believe they are but I don't remember off hand), then you could manually recover the settings, but remember that some settings will have changed in this new version of compiz, and you might be better off starting from scratch (unfortunately). I had to do the same on my system, because the settings are not transferred from the older version (different gconf root keys).

Comment: @DaveMG: It would have been difficult to do, since compiz 0.9.x was a complete rewrite.

Comment: @DaveMG: well, you have to understand that compiz is not maintained by some big company, but rather by a few people, and currently most of the work is done by one man - so that big things like documentation and migration are not trivial.